# Angular ng2-search-filter filter multiple

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 8 with [ng2-search-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter) to filter a list.

I have the following code:

```
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search by Title, Keyword, or File Type.." name="search" autofocus [(ngModel)]="filterBar">
```

...

```
<tr *ngFor="let media of medias | orderBy: key : reverse | filter:filterBar | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
  <td>{{media.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

This works as expected, and filters the list on the value entered in the search bar.

**Question**

Is it possible to filter on two items?

I would like to add a dropdown box, where if the user selects an item, it also filters on that item.

For example:

```
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Order By</mat-label>
              <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let media of medias">{{media.type}}</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>
```

I would like an additional filter on the selected `media.type`.

More info:

Here is the json data:

```
medias = [
    {
      "id":"1",
      "name": "Video File 1",
      "type": "Videos"
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "name": "Interactive Video File 1",
      "type": "Interactive Videos"
    },
    {
      "id":"3",
      "name": "Audio File 1",
      "type": "Audio"
    },
    {
      "id":"4",
      "name": "Image File 1",
      "type": "Images"
    },
    {
      "id":"5",
      "name": "Document File 1",
      "type": "Documents"
    },
    {
      "id":"6",
      "name": "Video File 2",
      "type": "videos"
    },
    {
      "id":"7",
      "name": "Audio File 2",
      "type": "Audio"
    },{
      "id":"8",
      "name": "Image File 2",
      "type": "Images"
    },{
      "id":"9",
      "name": "Video File 3",
      "type": "Videos"
    },{
      "id":"10",
      "name": "Document File 2",
      "type": "Documents"
    }
  ];
```